# frequency count on considering four columns in r

Tags: r, merge, count

currently i am trying to count frequency of set of sequence of data frame.

```
A  B
1  a
1  b
1  c
2  a
2  b
2  c
```

i have this data frame and i would like to count frequency of "B" of another data frame looking like this

```
C  D
1  a
1  a
1  b
1  b
2  b
2  c
2  c
```

As you can see the number of rows is different so datatable(counts) does not work. i would like to it to look like this after frequency count is done

```
a  b  freq
1  a   2
1  b   2
1  c   0
2  a   0
2  b   1
2  c   2
```

As you can see it makes counts of all the frequency even the 0 as the on some groups there is no data on it.

thanks for anyone that helps!

Answer (score 2):

By using `merge` and `aggregate`

```
df2$freq = 1
df = merge(df1,aggregate(freq~.,df2,length),by.x = c('A','B'),by.y = c('C','D'),all.x = T)
df[is.na(df)] = 0
df
  A B freq
1 1 a    2
2 1 b    2
3 1 c    0
4 2 a    0
5 2 b    1
6 2 c    2
```

More Info

```
aggregate(freq~.,df2,length)
  C D freq
1 1 a    2
2 1 b    2
3 2 b    1
4 2 c    2
```

Data Input

```
df1
  A B
1 1 a
2 1 b
3 1 c
4 2 a
5 2 b
6 2 c

df2
  C D
1 1 a
2 1 a
3 1 b
4 1 b
5 2 b
6 2 c
7 2 c
```

Comment: the number of rows is doubled and frequency is just either 1 or 0 rather than the actual count

Comment: @signalstone can you try this method with your sample data ?

Comment: @it does not seem to work and also on your more info set i need the 0 to show

Comment: @signalstone did you see the merge ? and fill na step ?

Comment: also it says "Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'freq' not found"

Comment: @signalstone check the first line ..`df2$freq = 1` assign a new value

Comment: @does not seem to work  it just merges the data add the group number on B in front of each row and frequency count is all NA

Comment: @signalstone using the data I was using and run the method . let us see the result on your end

Comment: hmm results are right. i don't understand why it won't work for my data :(

Comment: @signalstone which mean the data you provide here , can not reproduce your problem ..

Answer (score 1):

```
df1_rows = Reduce(paste, df1)
df2_rows = Reduce(paste, df2)    
data.frame(df1, freq = sapply(df1_rows, function(x) sum(df2_rows %in% x)),
           row.names = NULL)
#  A B freq
#1 1 a    2
#2 1 b    2
#3 1 c    0
#4 2 a    0
#5 2 b    1
#6 2 c    2
```

**DATA**

```
df1 = data.frame(A = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L),
                 B = c("a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c"))

df2 = data.frame(C = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L),
                 D = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c"))
```

Comment: when i use this frequency count is 0 and for some reason the B they add text to the front of each row on column b

Comment: would there be a problem if the my B and D were numbers such as 000856 or 900864?

Comment: i did but i had to change df2 because there are more rows in df2.

Comment: so A,B has only 2 columns while C,D have multiple columns in their page so i have to specify the columns i want to use

Comment: i did specify data.frame(busdata, freq = sapply(busdata_rows, function(x) sum(bus143_1$boardstation  %in% x)),
row.names = NULL) but when data comes out all the frequency is 0

Answer (score 1):

This looks to be a question of how to tabulate frequencies across two factors without dropping missing levels.

Here's the `dplyr` solution. This assumes that `dfAB`, as in your example data, contains no duplicates (`dfAB` is interchangeable with the output of `expand.grid` if you don't already have the level combinations in a data frame)

```
library(dplyr)
dfAB %>%
  # need at least one non-joining variable to tell matches from non-matches 
  left_join(mutate(dfCD, dummy = 1), by = c("A" = "C", "B" = "D")) %>% 
  group_by(A, B) %>%
  summarize(freq = sum(dummy, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   A [?]
      A     B  freq
  <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
1     1     a     2
2     1     b     2
3     1     c     0
4     2     a     0
5     2     b     1
6     2     c     2
```

(if there are duplicates in `dfAB`, add a `distinct` call to the chain before the join)

Comment: Error: `by` can't contain join column `C` which is missing from LHS

Comment: @signalstone "C" is in the RHS in my code, Check that you have copied it correctly.

Comment: @W, Murphy Column `B`/`boardstation` joining factor and character vector, coercing into character vector  - my d is name is boardstation which should be the same. but answer just comes out as how many frequencies there are

Comment: That warning is OK to ignore unless the results are unreasonable. You could avoid it by converting B to character or D to factor (with B's levels) prior to the join if you really wanted to

Comment: @signalstone "answer just comes out as how many frequencies there are"  Isn't that what you were asking for?

Comment: answer just is one number. which is the number of data count at 43349

Comment: You need to change the variable names in `group_by(A, B)` to match your real variable names

Comment: currently im using A,B,unique,boardstation. i changed all columns to as.character and when i run the program it comes out as one obs. of 1 vairable 43239